# Can you tell if an API request hasn't come through Azure API Management?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management

I have an API that runs on an Azure app service which is exposed through Azure API Management. Is there a way to tell if any requests are hitting the app service URL directly without going through the API Management service?

Comment: please can someone clarify why this question got marked down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, apim can't record those requests which hitting the app service url directly because these requests have no relationship with apim. If you want to record these requests, you need to modify the api in your code.

For example, you can add a parameter with a specific value in api management and when your code recieve this parameter, you can check the value to know if it comes from apim.

I assume that you want to prevent calling the app service url directly. So I suggest you adding White list on your server so that only apim request can visit your server.

For adding access restriction, if you're using azure app service, you can learn about this [ms document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions#add-or-edit-access-restriction-rules-in-the-portal).

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tinywa, you are correct I want to stop direct access but can't do that without knowing which users are using the API directly so they can change over before I make a breaking change. Looks like I will need to add in a param and track requests that way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you were to enabled Application Insights on both the API Management and APP Service you can view the requests on Application Insights for the APP Service to tell which ones were direct calls and which ones came from API Management.